# Empty $_FILES array when uploading file to PHP

Tags: php, mysql

As mentioned in the title uploading a file to the server fails with different warnings.

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
function getBack()
{
    echo "<script>window.location = 'newimage.php';</script>";
    die;
}
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "projectphp";
    $link = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
    if(mysqli_connect_error()){
        setcookie("error", "Problems with SQL connection", time() + 3600, "/");
        getBack();
    }
    if (getimagesize($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name']) == false) {
        setcookie("error", "Please Select An Image", time() + 3600, "/");
        //getBack();
    }

    $image = $_FILES["imagefile"]["tmp_name"];
    $name = $_FILES["imagefile"]["name"];
    $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents(addslashes($image)));

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user (photo) VALUES ('$name', '$image')";

    if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        echo "Image uploaded successfully.";
    } else {
        echo "Image Failed to upload";
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML part:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<!--- Header -->
<?php //include "headconfig.php"?>
<!--- Main --->
<div class="main">
    <div class="inner_main">
        <div class="form">
            <form action="" enctype=”multipart/form-data” method="post">
                <?php
                if(isset($_COOKIE["error"])){
                    echo "<span style='color: red'>".$_COOKIE["error"]."</span><br>";
                    setcookie("error", "", time()-3600, "/");
                }
                ?>
                <input type="file" name="imagefile" class="input" style="border: none" id="imagefile">
                <input type="submit" class="button" value="Upload" name="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--- Footer --->
<div class="footer">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When uploading a file these warnings and errors can be observed:

> Notice: Undefined index: imagefile in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPHP\newimage.php on line 18
>
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPHP\newimage.php on line 18
>
> Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPHP\newimage.php on line 18
>
> Notice: Undefined index: imagefile in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPHP\newimage.php on line 23
>
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPHP\newimage.php on line 23
>
> Notice: Undefined index: imagefile in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPHP\newimage.php on line 24
>
> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPHP\newimage.php on line 24
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPHP\newimage.php on line 25 Image Failed to
>   upload

Comment: You use `$_FILES['imagefile']` that does not exists in array. Show your `$_FILES` array

Comment: How to show ```$_FILES``` array?

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES)` and post output

Comment: There nothing. Also when i execute ```count($_FILES)```, there is 0

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. There is no obvious error in your posted code but I would recommend to switch `”multipart/form-data”` to `"multipart/form-data"` as the currently used double quotes are Non-ASCII characters and might cause problems. Also check if file uploads have been disabled in php.ini (setting `file_uploads=Off`).

Comment: Thank you, it was the solution

Answer (score 0):

Passed parameter should be a non-empty array.

Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPHP\newimage.php on line 18, which means that the array you're passing it's null and has nothing inside make sure the file you're uploading is getting in array.

comment this:

```
/* if (getimagesize($_FILES['imagefile']['tmp_name']) == false) {
    setcookie("error", "Please Select An Image", time() + 3600, 
    "/");
    //getBack();
} */
```

try var_dump($image); to see the variable information.

Comment: ```$image``` is not array

Comment: array(0) { }
Notice: Undefined index: imagefile in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPHP\newimage.php on line 23

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPHP\newimage.php on line 23

Notice: Undefined index: imagefile in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPHP\newimage.php on line 24

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPHP\newimage.php on line 24

Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjectPHP\newimage.php on line 25
Image Failed to upload

Comment: Okay so there's problem with file upload. Wait.